# Disable minifcation for Gatsby build

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

With the production build of my Gatsby project something is wrong. I see the following errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    React 6
    S scheduler.production.min.js:13
    T scheduler.production.min.js:14
react-dom.production.min.js:131:277
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    React 6
    S scheduler.production.min.js:13
    T scheduler.production.min.js:14
react-dom.production.min.js:131:277
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    React 6
    S scheduler.production.min.js:13
    T scheduler.production.min.js:14
4 react-dom.production.min.js:131:277
Uncaught Error: Minified React error #423; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=423 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    React 6
    S scheduler.production.min.js:13
    T scheduler.production.min.js:14
react-dom.production.min.js:293:38
```

I'm trying to disable minification to be able to find the source of this problems. How can this be done?

I've found https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3778, but maybe it's somehow possible nowadays? It's very hard to find the source of this error otherwise.

Comment: The solution was to migrate away from Gatsby. The grass on the other side is so much greener!